# Looking for learning resources

Tags: advice-request

I am an undergraduate student of Computer Science and am very interested in learning the theoretical part of it all.

Unfortunately, none of the subjects we have in our UG program give us an insight of theoretical part of Computer Science.
We do have the subjects *Automata* and *Graph Theory*, but our syllabus is very limited.

I have been looking for resources to learn the theory of computer science from the base up, for quite some time now.
I have already tried reading papers, completed MOOCs.

Somehow, I am always dissatisfied with the material. It is either too complicated (I don't even understand the notation used) or too trivial (teaching bits and bytes).

Could someone please provide me with some resources to learn theoretical computer science.
If possible, sort it in the order in which I should read it, so that the majority of prerequisites of the nth entry in the list, are covered in the preceding n-1 entries.

Please keep in mind:

- I am really interested in learning it.
- I have a decent background in programming, and have worked with several programming languages.
- This is not a *What videos/papers/books should everyone watch/read* question. I am simply looking for some introductory resources, which are neither too obvious, nor too complicated.

I have had 3 semesters of College level Maths.
Also, I have studied the material provided by ocw.mit.edu, for the courses: *18.03*, *18.062J* and *18.400J* mentioned at http://math.mit.edu/academics/undergrad/major/course18C/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is interesting. However, you forgot to mention one very important thing: What is your math background?

Comment: [This page](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/fa2012/resources.html) from my algorithms course site may be helpful.  See especially the review resources at the bottom of the page.

Comment: In your edited question, I would suggest you to provide little more details. E.g. 18.062J (Mathematics for Computer Science) and what textbook/material were used in the class. Did you look at JeffE's page?

Comment: Definitely this must be in your bookcase: [M. Sipser, Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Computation-Michael-Sipser/dp/113318779X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1375358947)

Comment: I think this question is off-topic here. Please check [help/on-topic]. This question is more suitable for [cs.se].

Comment: You could also try this book of David Harel:
http://www.amazon.com/Algorithmics-Spirit-Computing-David-Harel/dp/0321117840

It gives a "bird's eye" view of TCS, without delving into too much technical details. From there, you can continue to whatever attracts you more.

Comment: This question is certainly not "off-topic" here. And if "formally" it is (by some sets of regulations), then the formalities should probably be changed. Many of the users here are also teachers and part of their job is undergrad and graduate teaching, oriented to TCS. So what kind of undergraduate teaching optimizes a student's skills in doing later research in TCS is part of their interest as researchers.

Comment: @Dilworth, I don't see any research orientation in this question, it is simply a student who wants to learn more. This is not an outreach site for undergraduates. Typical questions by undergraduate students are off-topic on this site and that is very explicit in the definition of cstheory's scope, see [help/on-topic]. Such questions should be posted on [cs.se] which was partly created for answering this type of questions.

Comment: @Kaveh, as I said before; the formalities are not what is important here; they are set to help the site become better (for TCS), and not the opposite. The undergrad education needed for specializing in TCS is evidently of great importance to any researcher in the field. The OP is seeking specifically to get more knowledge in TCS, and this is certainly related to being a better researchers in grad school. Whether the OP explicitly wrote that he intends this question to assist in graduate education is irrelevant also, since we are not in a legal setting here.

Comment: @Dilworth, and as I said, this is not a formality: you should understand that this is not a general forum, it is a Q&A site with a particular scope. Out-reach to undergraduate students who might become interested in grad school is not a goal here. Typical questions by undergraduate students are _explicitly_ off-topic. If you want an analogy, this site if research, for teaching please use [cs.se]. Also, it is important how a question is phrased, it indicates if the question is in our scope or not.

Comment: @Kaveh, this is not a typical question. Typically undergraduate do not seek to learn TCS. The question is specific to TCS, it relates strongly to grad studies, it is answered nicely and the OP accepted the answer. To go back and discuss whether this question is or not off-topic here, in order to apply some formal regulations is a formality. This site is indeed not a general forum, but it has a goal (one of which is to help, promote and advance TCS research). By sticking narrowly to formal "definitions" about this site, and closing reasonable questions, we go against its goal.

Comment: @Dilworth, I think it is typical, my student do ask such questions. I wanted to clarify for you why I wrote this question is off-topic. There are many other things one can do with the goal of advancing TCS research but that will not make them appropriate on this site. The main purpose of this site is for researchers to help each other and not teaching undergraduates.

Comment: @Kaveh, certainly, hurting the advance of TCS, by closing reasonable questions (and by that promoting negative feelings among future researchers) is against the goal of this site. And so I would presume should be avoided. See also Noam Nisan's post against aggressive closing of questions here: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/aggressive-closing-of-questions

Comment: @Kaveh, also, the fact that your students ask you this question, if indeed, doesn't make the question typical.

Comment: @Dilworth, too much dramatization. If a student knocks on a professors door during a research meeting to ask a question like this his question will be politely denied and he would be asked to drop by during an office hour. Same here. The appropriate place to ask this question is [cs.se]. (I don't think Noam's post is relevant here.)

Comment: @Kaveh, well, as I explained above, I think this is (and should) be the appropriate place to ask questions like this. Noam's post (and its high rankings) supports my claim about a potential harm that may be caused by aggressive closing practices in this site.

Comment: @Dilworth, I think you don't understand the topic of Noam's post (which is not surprising since you are new here). It is OK for you to have whatever opinion you want to have about how this site _should be_ but as a moderator I have to explain the scope as it _is_. Undergraduate level questions are not welcome on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, plenty of introductory resources are available and it is impossible to be objective here. So what follows is merely my biased choice.

I would definitely start with reading something on algorithms and on discrete mathematics (possibly in parallel). Here, I would recommend the following books:

- [Introduction to Algorithms, by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844)
- [The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms, by Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201000296)
- [Invitation to Discrete Mathematics, by Matoušek and Nešetřil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198570422)

The first book mentioned is one of the most widely known resources on algorithms, suitable as an introductory resource. The second book is little bit older and more theoretical, however imho still valuable. The third book is (in my opinion) an excellent and readable introduction to various parts of discrete mathematics.

Later, I would recommend to focus on formal languages and automata theory. Here, my choice is the following book:

- [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation, by Hopcroft Ullman and Motwani](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321455363)

You might also like to consult the Sipser's book mentioned in one of the comments.

Of course, if you have some background, there may not be a need for you to thoroughly study these textbooks. However, it is imho necessary to have a stable grounding in the above mentioned subjects before proceeding any further. Thus, it may be sensible for you to consult the above mentioned resources and focus on the material that you find new and/or interesting.

After mastering these preliminaries, there are plenty of choices where to continue. In my opinion, you should definitely study some complexity theory. Here, I would recommend the following book:

- [Computational Complexity, by Papadimitriou](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201530821)

You also might be interested in some slightly more advanced (or, let us say, intermediate) mathematical methods used in the analysis of algorithms. Here, the following resource is considered to be classic:

- [Concrete Mathematics, by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025)

Some basics of optimization (especially linear programming) are a must for computer scientists. Here, I would recommend the following gentle introduction:

- [Understanding and Using Linear Programming, by Matoušek and Gärtner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540306978)

A well written (and not very demanding) introduction to randomized algorithms is the following:

- [Design and Analysis of Randomized Algorithms, by Hromkovič](http://books.google.sk/books/about/Design_and_Analysis_of_Randomized_Algori.html?id=EfuMfn8T5_oC&redir_esc=y)

Finally, some nice books on advanced algorithms and/or computation theory include:

- [The Design and Analysis of Algorithms, by Kozen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387976876)
- [Theory of Computation, by Kozen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1846282977)
- [Algorithmics for Hard Problems, by Hromkovič](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540441344)
- [Complexity and Approximation, by Ausiello et al.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540654313)
- [Randomized Algorithms, by Motwani and Raghavan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521474655)

However, I would suggest reading these only after thoroughly mastering those mentioned above.

This is not a complete list, however. Many other excellent resources are available. The selection I have made is based on my personal bias. Moreover, I have included only resources focused on the "algorithmic part" of theoretical computer science. That is, the selection I have made is not only incomplete, but also very narrow.

And I have to mention that learning some more advanced math would be very helpful for you. My general advice is: the more mathematics you know, the better. It is more and more obvious that there is not any mathematics absolutely irrelevant to computer science.